# Struts2, in jsp page, img tag's attribute src ends with .action, Not working in latest Chrome browser

Tags: image, jsp, google-chrome, struts2

I am using Struts2, in my jsp page i have dynamically set `src` attribute which ends with `.action`. In my Firefox and IE it is calling action, but fails to call action in latest Chrome.

Need Help

```html
<img src="/CRD/onlineUser/jcaptchaImage.action" width="180px" id="captchaId" height="70px" />
</div>
<s:textfield name="jCaptchaResponse" value="" title='%{getText("app.onlineUser.tooltip.captcha")}' id="onlineUser_jCaptchaResponse" />

<s:a onclick="document.getElementById('captchaId').src = 'jcaptchaImage.action#' + Math.random();" title='%{getText("app.onlineUser.tooltip.reload")}' href="#">
  <img src="<s:url value=" /images/reloadIcon.png "/>" align="absmiddle" alt="<s:text name=" app.onlineUser.tooltip.reload "></s:text>"/>
</s:a>
```

I am getting following warning in console when I inspect element in chrome:

> "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/jpeg: "localhost/User/jcaptchaImage.action".";

Struts-config.xml file contains :

```
<action name="jcaptchaImage"
        class="org.uic.cc.crd.action.onlineUser.OnlineUserAction" method="captchaGenerator"> 
        <-- Interceptors are used here -->
        <result name="success" >tiles.registrationForm</result>
    </action>
```

Action OnlineUserAction.java contains method captchaGenerator()

```
 public String captchaGenerator() {
//Logic 
OutputStream outputStream = null;
    final String captchaId = request.getSession().getId();

            final BufferedImage image = getImageCaptchaService()
                    .getImageChallengeForID(captchaId, request.getLocale());

            // Encode to JPEG Stream

                outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image, IMAGE_FORMAT, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
return null;
}
```

Comment: I am getting following warning in console when I inspect element in chrome: "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/jpeg: "https://localhost/User/jcaptchaImage.action"."  Please Help

Comment: Are you sure that a resource location is correct?

Comment: Post your action and its configuration.

Comment: Why is the image src a file without a image type extension in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @RomaC , Yes resource location works fine with browsers other than chrome.

Comment: @Aleksandr, Its configuration is same as web based struts2 application, Its not reaching Action, Where as with other browsers its calling action correctly

Comment: @mmalmeida, src will redirect to action mentioned (as in struts2 application) which is configured in struts-config.xml file , then generate captcha and load in jsp page.

Comment: @AleksandrM , Is it fine now?

Comment: You need to return `none`/`null` from the action and not a `success`, if you are writing directly to the response output stream.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes i understand your point, my problem is , it is calling method in action class. Method is not getting executed.

Comment: ... And set appropriate response headers.

Comment: Yes I understand but only if method gets executed , but its not

Comment: Are you sure? Why do you see `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/jpeg` error then?

Comment: Yes, like i said it works fine for all browsers except google chrome that clears everything i guess and that errror is related to chrome only. I googled around but could not get any answer :( .

Comment: Why not just set the mimetype correctly?

Comment: @DaveNewton, Thanks for your response. mime type set in the action class is  response.setContentType("text/jpeg"); And value i am passing from src ends with DOT action (.action). What could be the possible MIMEtype ?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes Its correct, after adding required MIME type , that error went off in chrome, but it still could not call action :( . Tried all possibilties

Comment: If you're getting that response back then it's calling the action.

Comment: Yes its calling action only on page load once, but when reload link is clicked, it should call action via src attribute. Problem is on click on reload link.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that anywhere in your question nor in comments.

Comment: @AleksandrM , I have mentioned as " dynamically set src attribute which ends with .action". I presume it means on reload. I apologize if its not communicated properly.

Comment: You are missing `/CRD/onlineUser/` part in your onclick.

Comment: thanks, but after adding also it is same :( :( not able to call action :(

Comment: Is there any other possible ways to call action apart from mentioning in src Nor submit the form ? Like only captcha image should be loaded on click of reload.

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses @AleksandrM, #DaveNewton #mmalmeida. Issue is resolved finally :) I replaced '#' with '?' in src value i.e.. jcaptchaImage.action# to jcaptchaImage.action? . it worked . Thanks again :)

Comment: @shazakham: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved finally :) I replaced '#' with '?' in src value i.e.. jcaptchaImage.action# to jcaptchaImage.action? . it worked . Thanks Everyone :)
`

```
<img src="/CRD/onlineUser/jcaptchaImage.action" width="180px" id="captchaId" height="70px" />
</div>
<s:textfield name="jCaptchaResponse" value="" title='%{getText("app.onlineUser.tooltip.captcha")}' id="onlineUser_jCaptchaResponse" />

<s:a onclick="document.getElementById('captchaId').src = 'jcaptchaImage.action?' + Math.random();" title='%{getText("app.onlineUser.tooltip.reload")}' href="#">
  <img src="<s:url value=" /images/reloadIcon.png "/>" align="absmiddle" alt="<s:text name=" app.onlineUser.tooltip.reload "></s:text>"/>
</s:a>
```

`